# Can you name this sorting algorithm?

Tags: c#, sorting

I have basic knowledge in C#, I read a bit about sorting algorithms but I haven't been able to identify this one.
I wrote it in C#, and the program takes a list of strings as input and outputs them in sorted order.
If you can name this algorithm please do so.

```
List<string> inputStrings = new List<string>();
string currentString = "";
Console.WriteLine("Enter strings and when you want to stop type '$$$'.");
while (currentString != "$$$")
{
    currentString = Console.ReadLine();
    if (currentString != "$$$")
        inputStrings.Add(currentString);
}
for (int i = 0; i < inputStrings.Count - 1; i++)
{
    for (int k = i + 1; k < inputStrings.Count; k++)
    {
        if (inputStrings[i].CompareTo(inputStrings[k]) > 0)
        {
            string tempString = inputStrings[i];
            inputStrings[i] = inputStrings[k];
            inputStrings[k] = tempString;
        }
    }
}
Console.WriteLine("These are the strings shown in sorted order:");
for (int i = 0; i < inputStrings.Count; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(inputStrings[i]);
}
```

Comment: Bubble Sort (I can't believe this is my [second time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35715226/what-kind-of-sort-algorithm-did-i-just-write#comment59106747_35715226) saying the *exact* same comment in a *single* week!)

Comment: `inputStrings.OrderBy(x => x)` is much simpler to write.

Comment: This looks like selection sort and bubble sort had a baby.

Comment: It isn't a bubble sort, because it doesn't have "bubbles". It is comparing an element with any other element, instead of comparing them only at distance = 1. It is more similar to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort, simplified because it exchanges immediately instead of waiting for the end of the inner cycle.

Comment: @crashmstr - yes, that is a good way to do it.  IMHO, beginners should understand what's going on under the hood, before they start using shortcuts.

Comment: I'm starting to re-think my answer.  I was always taught that two nested for-loops was a bubble sort.  Apparently, that doesn't necessarily jive with the industry-accepted definition.

Comment: @crashmstr But that's no fun!

Comment: The thing about learning sort algorithms: once you've learned them, you almost never need to know anything about them again if you work with languages that have good libraries with built-in sorting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is [*Selection Sort*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort)

> The algorithm divides the input list into two parts: the sublist of items already sorted, which is built up from left to right at the front (left) of the list, and the sublist of items remaining to be sorted that occupy the rest of the list. Initially, the sorted sublist is empty and the unsorted sublist is the entire input list. The algorithm proceeds by finding the smallest (or largest, depending on sorting order) element in the unsorted sublist, exchanging (swapping) it with the leftmost unsorted element (putting it in sorted order), and moving the sublist boundaries one element to the right.

The value of `i` represents the boundary between the portion of the array that is already sorted and the portion that needs to be sorted.

This implementation is non-orthodox in that it swaps the value in place immediately, rather than waiting for the nested loop to complete. However, the characteristic part of selection sort, which is searching for the next greater value linearly in the unsorted part, is present in this implementation.

This will have negative effect on the performance, because the overall number of swaps will grow from O(n) to O(n<sup>2</sup>).

To see why this is going to happen, consider the worst case for this algorithm, when the array is sorted in reverse order. When this happens, each iteration will "move" the remaining portion of the array by one element (`|` mark represents the sorted/unsorted boundary):

```
| a b c d -- first iteration of the outer loop
    b a c d -- nested loop starts
    c a b d
    d a b c -- nested loop finishes
d | a b c -- second iteration of the outer loop
    d b a c
    d c a b
d c | a b -- third iteration of the outer loop
    d c b a
d c b | a -- final state
```

Comment: Not sure it is the `Selection sort`. It seems to be a simplified version of it (it always does the exchange immediately)

Comment: @xanatos You are right, the implementation is unusual in that it swaps right away, rather than waiting for the nested loop to complete. However, the characteristic part of selection sort, which is searching for the next smallest value linearly in the entire unsorted part, is there.

Comment: Yep... My same thought about Insertion Sort. I always called it "simple sort", because it is the first sort algorithm I learned.

Comment: This is not exactly "selection sort". If you take snapshots after each inner cycle is completed and compare it with snapshots of "selection sort" there will be difference in unsorted part of list. It will be *shaffled* (because of constant swap during inner cycle), while "selection sort" keep unsorted part the same, only swapping with smallest value. See animated picture on wiki, picture of this one will be different.

Comment: I wouldn't straight up call this "selection sort". It's a mix between selection sort and bubble sort, not sure if it has a name. Check my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35798034/can-you-name-this-sorting-algorithm/35798123#35798123) for more details

Comment: Thanks! What effect do you think this difference would have?

Comment: @PelegTsadok I think the effect is negative. Please see the edit.

Answer (score 1):

It's called a bubble sort.

You can optimize it by using an [Optimized Bubble Sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort#Optimizing_bubble_sort).

Also, I'd prefer not to use $$$ to end your input.  Why not simply ask for all string entered on one line, with a comma in between each string.  Then you can split the one input string on Comma, resulting in a list of sub-string.

Comment: It isn't a bubble sort, a bubble sort "follows" an element through the list rather than leaving it for the next time the nested loop starts working.

Comment: I was always taught that two nested for-loops was a bubble sort. Apparently, after some research, I see that doesn't necessarily jive with the industry-accepted definition.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a mix between [Selection sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort) and [Bubble sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort). Like selection sort, at the end of each iteration of `i`, the i-th element will be sorted. However, unlike selection sort, it doesn't look for the maximum remaining value, but instead swaps right away as soon as it finds a bigger value, which is what bubble sort does.

I don't think this exact algorithm has a name.